# 'str' object has no attribute 'seek'; 'str' object has no attribute 'read'

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, file-io, python-imaging-library

Here are the two errors

```
    Exception in Tkinter callback
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\seif- zizo\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2895, in open
        fp.seek(0)
    AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'seek'
    
    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
    
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\seif- zizo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
        return self.func(*args)
      File "C:/Users/seif- zizo/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/main.py", line 7, in resize
        IMG=Image.open(data1,'r')
      File "C:\Users\seif- zizo\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2897, in open
        fp = io.BytesIO(fp.read())
    AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'
```

Here is the code which throws these errors:

```
    from tkinter import Tk,Label,Entry,Button,RIDGE,SOLID
    from PIL import Image
```

the function in which resizes the image after taking the values from data1,data2,data3,data4

```
    def resize():
        IMG=Image.open(data1,'r')
        new_image=IMG.resize((data2,data3))
        x=new_image.show()
        y=new_image.save(data4)
        print(x)
```

The GUI application code:

```
window=Tk()
    window.title("MR RESIZE")
    window.iconbitmap(r"C:\Users\seif- zizo\Downloads\Google-Noto-Emoji-Smileys-10104-pile-of-poo.ico")
    window.geometry('500x250')
    text1=Label(text="IMAGE PATH",background="#E91EDA" ,fg="WHITE",width=22,height=5,relief=SOLID)
    text2=Label(text="NEW IMAGE WIDTH",background="#2471A3" ,fg="WHITE",width=22,height=5,relief=SOLID)
    text3=Label(text="NEW IMAGE HEIGHT",background="#1738B2" ,fg="WHITE",width=22,height=5,relief=SOLID)
    text4=Label(text="SAVE IMAGE AS",background="#24B41B",fg="WHITE",width=22,height=5,relief=SOLID)
    text1.grid(row=0,column=0,padx=5)
    text2.grid(row=0,column=1,padx=5)
    text3.grid(row=0,column=2,padx=5)
    text4.grid(row=0,column=3,padx=5)
    entry1=Entry(width=20,relief=RIDGE,borderwidth=3)
    entry2=Entry(width=20,relief=RIDGE,borderwidth=3)
    entry3=Entry(width=20,relief=RIDGE,borderwidth=3)
    entry4=Entry(width=20,relief=RIDGE,borderwidth=3)
    entry1.grid(row=1,column=0,padx=5,pady=5)
    entry2.grid(row=1,column=1,padx=5,pady=5)
    entry3.grid(row=1,column=2,padx=5,pady=5)
    entry4.grid(row=1,column=3,padx=5,pady=5)
    data1=entry1.get()
    data2=entry2.get()
    data3=entry3.get()
    data4=entry4.get()
    enter_btn=Button(text='ENTER',width=15,command=resize)
    enter_btn.grid(row=2,columnspan=2,column=1,padx=5,pady=5)
    for i in range(4):
        window.columnconfigure(i, weight=1, minsize=30)
        window.rowconfigure(i, weight=1, minsize=30)
    window.mainloop()
```

In the code above I am trying to rescale an image, then output the new image after rescaling it. The problem is I get these two errors and I don't know what to do.  How can I fix this code?

Comment: `IMG=Image.open(data1,'r')` what's `data1`? What version of PIL are you using?

Comment: It is because `data1` is empty string since you called `data1=entry1.get()` right after creating `entry1`.

Answer (score 0):

It is because `data1` is empty string since you called `data1=entry1.get()` right after creating `entry1`.

You should call `data1 = entry1.get()` inside `resize()` (same for `data2` .. `data4`):

```py
def resize():
    data1 = entry1.get().strip()
    data2 = entry2.get().strip()
    data3 = entry3.get().strip()
    data4 = entry4.get().strip()
    if data1 and data2 and data3 and data4:
        try:
            data2 = int(data2)
            data3 = int(data3)
            IMG=Image.open(data1,'r') # 'r' is not necessary
            new_image=IMG.resize((data2,data3))
            new_image.show()
            new_image.save(data4)
        except ValueError:
            print('Invalid value of width or height')
    else:
        print('Empty value found')
```